# Finding unique numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to use a set to find the unique numbers and get the sum from user entered numbers. I heard that arrays are easier but a set might just do for me. I don't know much about sets or what they do so any input would be fantastic. Much appreciated everybody!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class getdistinct 
{ 
   int dialr;
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   public double go()
   {
      double a = 0
      counter = 10;

      int total = 0;

      for (counter != 0)
      {
         int thisisnewnumber = scan.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Enter number that you want to add: ");
             if(newInteger < 0) 
             {
                 n = n + 1
                 dial = dial - 1;
             }
             else 
             {
                 System.out.println("wrong");
             }
      } 

      System.out.println("the total is ";
      return a;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please read the documentation for data structures like Set before asking a specific question.  There are many people here that would be happy to help as long as you show you care enough to try.  This site is not the place to find someone to do your homework for you.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html

Answer (score 2):

java.util.HashSet stores unique values. Made minor changes to your program to use Set to store unique values and calculate sum of unique values using for loop

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class quiz_assignment {
int counter;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public int go() {
    int a = 0;
    int n = 0;
    counter = 10;

    Set<Integer> unValues = new HashSet<Integer>();

    while (counter != 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter Integer: ");
        int newInteger = scan.nextInt();
        if (newInteger < 0) {
            unValues.add(new Integer(newInteger));
            n += newInteger;
            counter = counter - 1;
            a = a + newInteger;
        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("Must be negative integer, please try again");
        }
    }

    int unSum = 0;
    for (Integer value : unValues) {
        unSum += value;
    }

  System.out.println("The sum of all ten integers is: " + a);
    System.out.println("The sum of unique integers is: " + unSum);
    return n;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    quiz_assignment o = new quiz_assignment();
    o.go();
}
}
```

Comment: this is making the sum of distinct numbers and the total sum the same when i run it? wonder why?

Comment: scratch that. Also, I need to type the number of distinct integers that there are ex) "The number of intergers is ". How would i do that?

Comment: B. Simmons, try having a look at javadocs and/or searching for this simple answer

Answer (score 0):

Set has its implementation in various classes like HashSet, TreeSet, LinkedHashSet. Following is an example to explain Set functionality
I used here (HashSet).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class quiz_assignment 
{ 
   int counter;
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   Set<Integer> ditinctSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

   public int go()
   {
      int a=0;
      int n=0;
      counter = 10;

      int total = 0;

      while (counter != 0)
      {
         System.out.println("Enter Integer: ");
         int newInteger = scan.nextInt();

         if(!ditinctSet.contains(newInteger)){
              ditinctSet.add(newInteger);
         }

             if(newInteger < 0) 
             {
                 n+=newInteger;
                 counter = counter - 1;
                 a=a+newInteger;
             }
             else 
             {
                 System.out.println("Must be negative integer, please try again");
             }
      } 

      System.out.println("The sum of all ten integers is: " + a);
      System.out.println("Distinct numbers are: ");
      System.out.println(ditinctSet);
      return n;
   }
}
```

And here a link to start knoing more about sets.

Comment: like the other answer, yours is also saying it cant find the hashset symbol.. is it missing something?

Comment: Just add one import statement java.util.HashSet

Answer (score 0):

Hashsets are useful because they don't store duplicate entries. You can use them to store your set of unique numbers that the user inputs. I also removed the variable "a" from your code because its purpose seemed identical to variable n's.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class quiz_assignment{ 
int counter;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public int go()
{
  HashSet<Integer> distinctNumbers = new HashSet<>();
  int n=0;
  counter = 10;

  int total = 0;

  while (counter != 0)
  {
     System.out.println("Enter Integer: ");
     int newInteger = scan.nextInt();
         if(newInteger < 0) 
         {
             n+=newInteger;
             counter = counter - 1;
             distinctNumbers.add(newInteger);
         }
         else 
         {
             System.out.println("Must be negative integer, please try again");
         }
  } 
  int size = distinctNumbers.size();

  System.out.println("The sum of all ten integers is: " + n);

  System.out.println("You inputed " + size + " numbers.");

  System.out.println("Your numbers are:");

  for(Integer i: distinctNumbers){
       System.out.println(i);
  }



  return n;
 }
}
```

Comment: its saying that it can't find the HashSet symbol... how is that fixed?

Comment: Can you add your main method? I just ran it and it worked perfectly fine.